# how to handle form_for in rails namspaced controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, form-for

I have worked with rails scaffold to generate forms and views automatically.
But now I had to use namespaced controller with model in root namspace.

So, I generated controller manually without scaffold, I'm having trouble working with form.

I suppose that the following code should generate a form for namespaced controller

```
<%= form_for @menu do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :label %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :label %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :order %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :order %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

but it doesnt. it says

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

it seems very easy to do rails with scaffold generators, but if one wants to do manually, rails helper method turns negative on them.

I have searched for form_for documentation and changed the code to

```
<%= form_for @menu, :url => admin_menu_path do |f| %>
```

then it shows a different error that

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/menus"}
```

my rake routes gives the following output

```
     admin_root        /admin(.:format)                admin/menus#index
    admin_menus GET    /admin/menus(.:format)          admin/menus#index
                POST   /admin/menus(.:format)          admin/menus#create
 new_admin_menu GET    /admin/menus/new(.:format)      admin/menus#new
edit_admin_menu GET    /admin/menus/:id/edit(.:format) admin/menus#edit
     admin_menu GET    /admin/menus/:id(.:format)      admin/menus#show
                PUT    /admin/menus/:id(.:format)      admin/menus#update
                DELETE /admin/menus/:id(.:format)      admin/menus#destroy
```

correct me if I'm wrong, but I think ruby cannot find model Menu in Admin namespace, which is obvious.  So, I tried with ::Menu.new , I thought it would look up in upper namespace, but no result!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You might be forgetting to instantiate `@menu` in your controller.**

The message "undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class" says that `@menu` is `nil`.

Since `admin_menu_path` needs a Menu instance, Rails cannot generate the route correctly when `nil` is passed.

Once you have the instance variable properly set in your controller you can use:

```
form_for [:admin, @menu] do |f| ... end
```

Comment: yes it worked, but I dont understand how form_for works yet, I havnt added Menu.new in index method because it would create a new model. what shd I do if I want to put a form in index?

Comment: It only creates a new instance of `Menu`, not a record in the database. It's the easiest and most recommended way to make a form for a database resource. Here you can get some information about how `form_for` works: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Answer (score 0):

Something like `form_for [:admin, @menu] do |f| ... end` should work. Similar question here: [Nested resources in namespace form_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718059/nested-resources-in-namespace-form-for)