# Rails: Edit Form results in duplicates when edited(nested resources inside a namespace)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working with nested resources that have a, `has_many` through association.

Trying to simply edit my dynamic_elements values, but the when the edit page is generated the form button is primed to complete a post action. I've read a little that rails does this because some browsers don't support PUT so it just goes ahead with a Post. Ive also read to keep the form from making this duplicate that all I have to do is put the `:id` in the strong params. The only problem with this is that `:id` is not making it into the paramaters when I submit the form. The `:id` is present in params for the edit view, but as soon as I hit submit they are no where to be found. Here's some code:

here, you can see the paramters of `{"dynamic_page_id"=>"2", "id"=>"31"}` are present for the edit method/view but as soon as the update method is called, the `"id"=>"31"` is lost

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHKT8.png)

routes:

```
namespace :admin do
 resources :dynamic_pages do
  resources :dynamic_elements
 end
end
```

rake routes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW9zr.png)

Models:

```
module Admin
 class DynamicElement < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dynamic_page_elements
  has_many :dynamic_pages, :through => :dynamic_page_elements
 end
end

module Admin
 class DynamicPage < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dynamic_page_elements
  has_many :dynamic_elements, :through => :dynamic_page_elements
 end
end

module Admin
 class DynamicPageElement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :market_page
  belongs_to :market_element
 end
end
```

Controller:

```
module Admin
  class DynamicElementsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_dynamic_element, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
   before_action :set_dynamic_page, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
   @dynamic_elements = DynamicElement.all
   # @dynamic_page = DynamicPageElement.find(params[:dynamic_page_id])
  end

   def show
   end

   def new
    @dynamic_element = DynamicElement.new
   end

   def edit
    @dynamic_element = DynamicElement.find(params[:id])
    @styles_hash = @dynamic_element.style
   end

   def create
    # @dynamic_element = DynamicElement.find(params[:id])
   @dynamic_element = DynamicElement.new(dynamic_element_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @dynamic_element.save
      format.html { redirect_to admin_dynamic_page_dynamic_elements_url, notice: 'Dynamic element was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @dynamic_element }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @dynamic_element.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
  @dynamic_page_element = DynamicPageElement.new(dynamic_element_id: @dynamic_element.id, dynamic_page_id: params[:dynamic_page_id])
  @dynamic_page_element.save
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @dynamic_element.update(dynamic_element_params)
      format.html { redirect_to admin_dynamic_page_dynamic_elements_path, notice: 'Dynamic element was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @dynamic_element }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @dynamic_element.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  @dynamic_page_element = DynamicPageElement.where(dynamic_element_id: params[:id])[0]
  @dynamic_page_element.destroy
  @dynamic_element.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to admin_dynamic_page_dynamic_elements_path, notice: 'Dynamic element was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_dynamic_element
    @dynamic_element = DynamicElement.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_dynamic_page
    @dynamic_page = DynamicPage.find(params[:dynamic_page_id])
  end

  def dynamic_element_params
    params.permit(:style, :description, :id)
  end

 end
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_with(url:admin_dynamic_page_dynamic_elements_url) do |form| %>
 <% if dynamic_element.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(dynamic_element.errors.count, "error") %> 
    prohibited this dynamic_element from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
     <% dynamic_element.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
     <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
 <%= form.label :description %>
 <%= form.text_field :description, value: @dynamic_element.description %>
</div>

<div class="field">
 <%= form.label :style %>
 <%= form.text_area :style, value: @styles_hash %>
</div>

<h5>Current Styles</h5>
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
 <% @dynamic_element.style.keys.zip(@dynamic_element.style.values).each do |key, value| %>
   <li>"<%= key %>" => "<%= value %>", </li>
  <% end %>
 </ul>

 <div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

instead of `url:admin_dynamic_page_dynamic_elements_url` in my form helper, i've tried, `model: @market_page`, but only to be thrown this error:

```
undefined method `admin_dynamic_element_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ffe56cf57b8>:0x007ffe56c45340>
Did you mean?  admin_dynamic_page_path
               admin_dynamic_pages_path
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl3ac.png)

I just cannot seem to figure this out, any help would be appreciated. If I need to provide more info please tell me! Thank you!

Comment: Could you please show backtrace where exactly this undefined method error is raised?

Comment: Okay I took a screenshot of what i believe you are looking for.

Comment: I also added a screenshot of the terminal between the edit and update methods
@ahawrylak

Comment: This is the answer that helped me, after many hours of searching. So simple. 
Anyway, for anyone in the future, this is how to set up a form for nested resources inside a namespace
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2728435/10713838

Comment: Also, you can know at any time what your routes are by executing `rails routes` in the terminal (`rake routes` if rails < 5)